# eliminate white spaces between words using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to eliminate white space between 2 words among sentence containing many words

My code looks like this:

```
import re
sentence = "open app store"
pattern = re.compile(r'\b([a-z]) (?=[a-z]\b)', re.I)
sentence = re.sub(pattern, r'\g<1>', sentence)
print(sentence)
```

output:

```
open app store
```

I want to remove white space between app and store. I want output like this "open appstore".

Note that `app` won't always come up with `store`, `app` can come along with some other word after it, e.g. `app maker`.

Comment: What rule are you applying so that it becomes `open appstore` and not `openapp store` ?

Comment: Do you want to remove the whitespace before the last word in a string? See https://ideone.com/uYTWnZ

Comment: What is your rule? If `app store` may come anywhere in the string, how do you want to match it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: `app store` can come anywhere in sentence. I want to match `app store` string in sentence and replace it with `appstore`.

Comment: See my answer explaining the problem and 2 solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at [your pattern](https://regex101.com/r/SwPkX4/1): it matches a word boundary, then captures any ASCII letter into Group 1, then matches a space, and then asserts there is a single ASCII letter followed with a word boundary. So, it can match `a b` in `My a b string`, but not the `app store`.

Now, it seems your `app` value is static, after it you want to match 1 or more whitespaces only if there is another word following `app`. You may follow two strategies.

You may match `app` that is followed with whitespace(s) and a letter and then remove the whitespaces (see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/cyxPFA)):

```
re.sub(r"\b(app)\s+([a-z])", r"\1\2", sentence, flags=re.I)
```

(also, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qOpQSR/1)) or you may use the known words that follow `app` and only remove the spaces between them:

```
re.sub(r"\b(app)\s+(store|maker|market|etc)", r"\1\2", sentence, flags=re.I)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qOpQSR/2) and [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/zPn4vr).

Answer (score 1):

This could work for you.

```
>>> import re
>>> sentence = "this is an open app store and this is another open app store."
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'app[\s]store')
>>> replacement = 'appstore'
>>> result = re.sub(pattern, replacement, sentence)
>>> result
'this is an open appstore and this is another open appstore.'
```

Edit: You could use this function to eliminate whitespace(s) between any two words.

```
import re

def remove_spaces(text, word_one, word_two):
    """ Return text after removing whitespace(s) between two specific words.

    >>> remove_spaces("an app store app maker app    store", "app", "store")
    'an appstore, app maker, appstore'
    """

    pattern = re.compile(r'{}[\s]*{}'.format(word_one, word_two))    # zero or more spaces
    replacement = word_one + word_two
    result = re.sub(pattern, replacement, text)

    return result
```

Comment: "app" won't always come up with "store". "app" can come along with some other extension. e.g. "app maker". Can you please help me accordingly?

Comment: @Sonal, it still works. It seems you didn't test it with a different word after "app "

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

```
import re
sentence = "This is test"
pattern = re.compile(r'(.*)\b\s+(?=[a-z])', re.I | re.S)
sentence = re.sub(pattern, r'\1', sentence)
print(sentence)
```

Output : This istest

hope it works for you.

Comment: "app store" won't always be the last word of sentence. It can come anywhere in sentence.